# Weird Python profiling results: small function takes a long time

Tags: python, profiling

Since my script deals with massive amounts of data, I've been profiling it to shorten the execution times. After a long run I found this surprising result:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall   cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
190158700 2488.387    0.000  5282.776    0.000 bitcoin_types.py:214(_read)
 17483627 1523.197    0.000  3385.274    0.000 script.py:124(parse)
 17479677 1289.881    0.000  1289.881    0.000 {method 'Put' of 'leveldb.LevelDB' objects}
 52439034 1279.769    0.000  2234.548    0.000 StringIO.py:208(write)
   201841 1127.547    0.006 17186.404    0.085 validate.py:35(block)
248980529 1089.813    0.000  1089.813    0.000 {len}
 15064476 1021.241    0.000  1021.241    0.000 {method 'Delete' of 'leveldb.LevelDB' objects}
 26434944 1010.258    0.000  1010.258    0.000 {method 'Get' of 'leveldb.LevelDB' objects}
 63334845  896.935    0.000  2904.124    0.000 bitcoin_types.py:222(read_uint8)
152052558  896.330    0.000   896.330    0.000 {method 'update' of '_hashlib.HASH' objects}
144965272  819.315    0.000   819.315    0.000 {method 'read' of 'file' objects}
```

You can see `tottime = 2488.387`, which as far as I know, is the total time of running the function excluding the inner calls while `cumtime` is including. What's surprising about this is that `_read` is a very small function:

```
def _read(f, n, h=None):
    data = f.read(n)

    if h is not None:
        h.update(data)

    return data
```

How come `_read` is taking such a long `tottime` compared to `cumtime` even if it does pretty much nothing besides calling other functions? I'd expect `cumtime >>>>> tottime`! Is `is not None` such a expensive operation? Should I just `try-except` it?

Comment: ncalls is the number of times your function has been called. Does this answer your question?

Comment: percall is `0.000`. I think it's just that you are calling the function a ridonkulous number of times.

Comment: i would suspect the `h.update(data)` more than the `is not None`. how big are your data payloads, and is the key hash function expensive or prone to hash collisions?

Comment: @Blorgbeard updated the answer with more rows. Of course `percal = 0.000`, it's a VERY small function and most of my `percall = 0.000`. Most of these are, but they're looped over a huge list of huge files. Not surprising at all. How come this is the only one with such a huge `tottime` while it's probably the shortest function? **THAT's surprising!** Of course I'm calling the function a ridiculous number of times (all functions, actually), but it doesn't explain why its `tottime` > `tottime` for the inner `read` method while the inner read ought to be more expensive.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman no, `tottime` ignores the time of the inner functions. You mean `cumtime` (which AFAIK is `tottime` + the `tottime` of the inner called functions) but that wouldn't be surprising at all!

Comment: right.... forgot about that. i did a %timeit of a simple `dict.update()` vs. `is not None` on my system... the 'is not None` was about 47 ns, the `dict.update()` about 350 ns - so the None check should be an order of magnitude faster than the updates. yet the updates are faster? it is also weird that its cumtime is ~5.2k, while read + update together are only about 1.8k. there is still some time missing. is there a decorator on this function, or in a metaclass, by any chance?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman nope, I included as much as I could. The function is **that** short and it's a pure good-old function! Nothing fancy. This is driving me nuts! :( I'm starting to think it's actually a cProfile bug! The results are consistent across runs, by the way, so that's not an outlier.

Comment: Have you compared `cProfile` to the `profile` - module?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. Please provide a minimal *working* example that we can profile and see those results. Testing your `_read` function on my system outputs results that are not consistent with what you wrote here.